# C# Properties - returning one type and storing another

Tags: c#, properties

I have a class called Attribute, which contains a list. I want the get method to return true/false if a given string is present in the list. However, I want the set method to accept a string and add it to the list.

I don't have a compiler handy, but my code would more or less look like this. Is this possible to do?

```
class Attribute{

    private list<string> m_data;

    public bool this[string s] {
        get { return this.m_data.Contains[s]; }
        set { this.m_data.Add[s]; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible with that syntax.

Comment: This is really one of those times when trying it is the best course.  You already wrote the code.  Get to a compiler and try it.

Comment: why would you be writing code without being able to compile it.? what's the gain here..? create yourself a Method SomeMethod Boolean(pass in List<string>) have it return boolean Duh

Comment: since there is input, this would need to be a method

Comment: I'd love to know what your requirements are such that this design makes any sense.

Comment: I know not testing it is rather lazy ... I was mulling this over at work during some downtime, but they don't give us admin privileges on the computer.

As for why I chose this, I'm trying to figure out the best way to make an Item system for a game. I want to give items a list of attributes from a file ("Weapon", "Usable", etc). I thought the simplest method would be to just see if a given property exists, by invoking the name itself, but still allowing it to be handled "normally". I guess I'll find a more elegant solution then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but it's horrendously counter-intuitive.  Assignments to your property (which is actually an indexer) would have to contain some kind of Boolean value, which gets ignored and thrown away:

```
Attribute a = new Attribute();
a["test"] = true;                 // Adds "test" as expected -- but WTF does the true mean?
a["foo"] = false;                 // Adds "foo" -- the false means nothing
Console.Out.WriteLine(a["test"]); // returns true
```

So yes, you can do this.  But it's a bad idea, because no one maintaining the code will have a clue what's going on.  That dangling Boolean looks like it has some kind of meaning, but it doesn't; it violates the Principle of Least Astonishment when assigning true does the same thing as assigning false!  Not to mention, the value you pass in as an "index" really isn't an index into anything at all.  It's legal, but using syntax in a completely different way from what it's intended for.

In all honesty you'd be better served just accessing the `List<string>` directly and calling its existing `Contains()` and `Add()` methods.

Comment: Alright, I will have to do something more elegant and intuitive. Thank you!

Comment: If writing `false` had the effect of removing the item from the collection I think the behavior would seem perfectly fine and intuitive.  Think of it as a sparse array of Booleans, indexed by strings rather than integers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will work, however, keep in mind that you will have to set it as noted below. A somewhat bizarre usage of properties. Setting a value of either true or false will put the string in the list.

```
attribute["Test String 1"] = true;
attribute["Test String 2"] = false;
```

Testing whether the string is in the list or not is as you might expect:

```
Boolean result1 = attribute["Test String 1"]; // true
Boolean result2 = attribute["Test String 2"]; // true
Boolean result3 = attribute["Test String 3"]; // false
```

Comment: That absolutely works, but it's horrendously counter-intuitive.  The dangling boolean no-op assignment bakes my noodle.

Comment: Indeed. I have absolutely no idea why anyone would want to do this on purpose. (I'll leave it up to the rest of the comments and answers to explain why it's a bad idea.)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I wasn't sure it works, but I tried it and it compiles with some adjustments:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute( );
        attribute[ "string1" ] = true;
        attribute[ "string2" ] = false;

        Console.WriteLine( attribute[ "string1" ] ); //True
        Console.WriteLine( attribute[ "string2" ] ); //True        
        Console.WriteLine( attribute[ "string3" ] ); //False
    }
}

class Attribute {
    private List<string> m_data;

    public Attribute(){
        m_data = new List<string>();
    }

    public bool this[ string s ] {
        get { return this.m_data.Contains( s ); }
        set { this.m_data.Add( s ); }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It works perfectly without any problem but it seems very nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Although a read-write property is essentially a `get` method and a `put` method, and can't really do anything which such a pair of methods can't do, one can only get the syntactic sugar associated with properties if the methods are wrapped up in a "property", which poses various restrictions on the forms the methods can take.  Most notably, a property may not have multiple overloads of `set` those signatures differ only in type of parameter used to specify the new value, nor may it have a `get` method whose return type doesn't match the "new value" parameter of the `set` method, and whose parameters don't precisely match all the other parameters of `set`.

I'm not sure exactly what is gained by making the syntactic sugar only be available for properties meeting the above restrictions.  If a read-write property was simply a getter method juxtaposed with a setter method, it would be possible to have an abstract `ReadableFoo` type with an abstract `get` for property `Foo`, and have a derived `Mutablefoo` type which overrides the `get` and adds a `set`.  Unfortunately, that's not possible.  The best one can do is have the `ReadableFoo` method implement a non-virtual read-only `Foo` property which calls an abstract method; then `MutableFoo` can override the aforementioned method while replacing the read-only property with a read-write one (the `get` should chain to the aforementioned abstract method).

Your particular scenario looks like a workable way of doing what you want, though I would suggest that setting `a["George"]=false;` should remove "George" from the collection.  Many other scenarios where having multiple type overloads for a property setter might be useful, however, simply cannot be implemented in .net because the design of properties won't allow it.